# Why can slippage only be set to whole numbers using Raydium Swap SDK?

Tags: javascript, swap, raydium

I am currently using the Raydium SDK to perform token swaps. I use the Percent class from the sdk to create the slippage value which I then use in my transaction, but it seems that this Percent class only accepts whole number...

So as it is now the slippage can only be 1%, 2%, 3%...

Is there another method to rather have decimal slippage values instead of whole numbers?

Here is just an example of the percent object I create, where slippageBps is a number, such that if slippageBps was 5 then it would be 5 percent,

```
import { Percent } from '@raydium-io/raydium-sdk'
const slippage = new Percent(slippageBps, 100);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Percent class works as a fraction and thus if I just increase the denominator the percent values can become more accurate.

```
const slippage = new Percent(25, 10000);
```

This would yield a percentage value of 0.25%.